# Getting {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"} error even with open domain access policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

My AWS Elasticsearch domain have access policy like this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/some-user"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:domain/some-cluster/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Even with this policy I am not able to access kibana.
Does AWS ES have done some change in their access policies?

Comment: " I am not able to access kibana" - is not specific. How do you exactly try? What errors do you get.

Comment: I am trying with the aws provided link given on the console

Comment: How did it go? Do you know why it does not work based on my answer and how to address it?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't access ES directly** with just the link having this policy. The reason is that you **must sign** your requests with valid sigv4 signature. Every request to ES, due to your policy, must be signed by `some-user` that can only access it.

This is to ensure that only that user can access it, as you specified in the policy. For this reason you **can't use kibana**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html#es-kibana-access):

> Kibana does not natively support IAM users and roles

You have to **access your ES programmatically**, so that you can sign the requests. A popular tool for that is [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) for python.